# jQuery error when reading radio button values in Firefox but not in Safari

Tags: jquery, firefox, radio-button

I get the following error in Firefox/Firebug but not in Safari.

> $("input[name='how_many']:checked").val is not a function

Code follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#message-form").change(function(){

        var selectedRadio = $("input[name='how_many']:checked").val();

        if(selectedRadio == "some")
        {
              $("#conditional").fadeIn("slow");
        }else{
              $("#conditional").fadeOut("slow");
        };        
    });
});
```

Comment: Is one of the inputs checked by default? If not, jQuery can't find it, hence no value for it.

Comment: Yes, there are two radio buttons and one of them checked.

Comment: what is `#message-form` id for? i think u have `select box` then under that there is `radio boxex`?? will u please paste your code on jsfiddle.net so that we can answer u better.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d5Cke/ #message-form is the id for the form where these two radio buttons live. The radio button group is named 'how_many'.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this fixed it but I moved my scripts to the bottom in front of  and now it's working in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.